# datagridview does not save changes to Access MDB file by default?

Tags: vb.net

while user edits the datagridview, it does not save changes to Access MDB file ?

this is not working..

TableAdapter.Update(DataGridView1.DataSource)

Comment: Code...! Need to see some code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BindingSource.endedit()
adapter.update()
```

does a trick.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the data source explicitly.

The exact mechanism will depend on the data source attached to the view (via the `.DataSource` property).

```
dataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

will update the in memory `DataTable` object.

Comment: Unless I am very mistaken, AcceptChanges only commits changes to the in-memory DataTable, but does not propagate them to the database. You would need to call Update() on the DataAdapter attached.

Comment: If you post your code in the question it'll get correctly formatted (assuming you hit the "0101" icon) and it'll make more sense. I'm primarily a C# developer so I have to think a bit more when it comes to VB :)